# How to create load more listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, scroll

I want to create load more scrollview in listview. My app flow is storing youtube link in csv file and fetch this link from my app and display in my listview. But the problem is I don't want to wait too much load time when app is open.If I have a lot of youtube link in my csv.I will take a lot of time.So,for example I want to display only 5 video in initial state and when load more, display more 5 video in my list view.How can I do that.My code is below.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';
import 'videolist.dart';
import './models/models.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart' as csv;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class DisplayVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  String id;
  @override
  DisplayVideo(this.id);
  _DisplayVideoState createState() => _DisplayVideoState();
}

class _DisplayVideoState extends State<DisplayVideo> {
  late YoutubePlayerController _controller ;
  Future<List<YoutubeDetail>> _loadCSV() async {
    Map<String, String> allData = {
      'login': '',
      'password': '',
    };
    final Uri url = Uri.parse(
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JornaldRem/bedtime_story/main/videoId.csv');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    csv.CsvToListConverter converter =
        new csv.CsvToListConverter(eol: '\r\n', fieldDelimiter: ',');
    List<List> listCreated = converter.convert(response.body);
    // the csv file is converted to a 2-Dimensional list
    List<YoutubeDetail> youtubeDetailList = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < listCreated.length; i++) {
      YoutubeDetail temp = YoutubeDetail(
        listCreated[i][0],
        listCreated[i][1],
      );

      youtubeDetailList.add(temp);
    }
    return youtubeDetailList;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: widget.id,
      flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
        autoPlay: true,
        mute: false,
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text('Title'),
          toolbarHeight: 60,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF006666),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: YoutubePlayer(
                controller: _controller,
                liveUIColor: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: _loadCSV(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<List<YoutubeDetail>> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        List<YoutubeDetail> videoDetail = snapshot.data!;
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            itemCount: videoDetail.length,
                            itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                              if (index > 0) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 80,
                                    child: DisplayVideoView(
                                        videoDetail[index].url,
                                        videoDetail[index].title),
                                  ),
                                  onTap: (){
                                    String url = videoDetail[index].url;
                                    String id = url.substring(url.length - 11);
                                    print("HEllo");
                                    _controller.load(id);
                                    // DisplayVideo(id);
                                  }
                                );
                              } else {
                                return Container();
                              }
                            });
                      } else {
                        return Container();
                      }
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class DisplayVideoView extends StatelessWidget {
  String videopath;
  String title;
  DisplayVideoView(this.videopath, this.title);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String url = videopath;
    String id = url.substring(url.length - 11);
    // TODO: implement build
    return Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: Container(
        height: 150,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: Row(children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://img.youtube.com/vi/$id/mqdefault.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill)),
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(
            flex: 1,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 14,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this approach:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleWidgetState createState() => _ExampleWidgetState();
}

class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {
  List<Widget> _myList = [];

  void _loadFiveMore() {
    _myList = <Widget>[
      ..._myList,
      for (int i = _myList.length; i < _myList.length + 5; i++)
        ListTile(title: Text('item $i')),
    ];
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadFiveMore();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(children: [
          ..._myList,
          OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() => _loadFiveMore());
              },
              child: const Text('get 5 more'))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const ExampleWidget());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package.
have loadmore callback, refresh call back
https://pub.dev/packages/loadmore_listview

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33266575)